# What other archive formats save Date Created and Date Accessed?

Tags: compression, zip, archiving, 7-zip, date

**Compressing Files**

When zipping files with Windows' built-in zip utility, it will not save the Date Created in the archive:

[image: Send to Compressed (zipped) folder]

[image: Windows Archive Root Folder]

[image: Windows Archive Subfolder]

[image: 7-Zip Display]

Also, I just found a bug where **Windows will not save the Date Modified of directories in the root folder of the zip**!

7-Zip on Windows **will** save the Date Created and Date Accessed when compressing a .zip file :

[image: Add to zip 7-Zip]

[image: 7-Zip maintains ALL date values]

However it does not do this for its (referring to 7-Zip) native .7z format:

[image: Add to 7z 7-Zip]

[image: 7z file has no Date Accessed or Date Created values]

Any Unix-based formats are obviously ineligible.

.tar file:

[image: tar file]

Actually, it turns out .wim files can do this. I'll create an answer.

**Extracting Files**

Let's modify some of the files:

[image: First directory]

[image: Second diretory]

Assuming you created a .zip file with Date Created and Date Accessed and extract them:

[image: Extracting files]

**Date Created and Date Modified are set to the value!!!** This COMPLETELY invalidates the purpose of zipping an archive with Date Created.

[image: Date Created set to Date Modified]

Same if files are copied out of the zip:

[image: Copying files out of the zip]

However, if you extract with 7-Zip:

[image: Extracting with 7-Zip]

It preserves the Date Created attribute:

[image: Date Created preserved]

Are there any other formats out there that save these two fields within the archive format definition?

Comment: .7z is not a Windows native format...

Comment: "however it [referring to the subject 7-Zip] does not do this for its [referring to 7-Zip again] native .7z format." I was referring to .7z being the native format of 7-Zip, like .rar is to WinRAR and .ace is to WinAce.

Comment: It's really too bad to omit "unix-based" formats, because 7zip supports tar and (I believe) cpio creation and extraction.  Oh well.

Comment: But if they're Unix-based they'll never save Date Created.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can also store Access-, Modification- and Creation-Date when using 7-zips ".7z" format. To do so just specify the following parameters when packing data:

- 7-zip GUI: write "**tc ta**" into "Parameters:" textfield
- 7-zip command line: specify "**-mtc -mta -mtm**" parameters

*tc* stands for creation time,
*ta* stands for access time and
*tm* stands for modification time

The modification time is stored by default.

Comment: That worked! I also found a reference to [all of the other GUI parameters](https://sevenzip.osdn.jp/chm/cmdline/switches/method.htm#7Z). Thanks for the answer and sorry for not accepting it until now.

Answer (score 1):

Date Created, Modified and Accessed are not functions of file formats. 
Also, 7-Zip is not a Windows native application.

Regardless, these attributes are part of NTFS journaling.

You can add these attributes to Windows explorer easily for all folder / file types:

[image]

However, they are not always accurate or enabled.

On my machine, for example accessed journaling appears to be off. Right clicking and viewing properties of the a file, I see slightly different (and more accurate attributes)

[image]

I can also run a PowerShell command to get information

`gci | LastAccessTime` gives me:

[image]

It is just as accurate as the explorer view.

Instead, what needs to be done it ensure Windows has [jorunaling enabled.](http://www.groovypost.com/howto/microsoft/enable-last-access-time-stamp-to-files-folder-windows-7/)

This can be enabled from an administrator command prompt with the command:

```
fsutil behavior set disablelastaccess 0
```

Comment: I think you totally missed the point...

Comment: Doesn't answer the question. Most archive formats support Date Modified, but only one supports Date Created and Date Accessed (.zip by 7-Zip). OS X has a "Date Last Opened", which may be comparable to Date Accessed.

Comment: @jjlin how so? His question was misguided as time stamps are not a part of a format, they are a part of the File System. I directed him towards information on what is actually going on... Although I am running 3 hours of sleep in about 48 hours.

Comment: @NobleUplift .zip is not given any special level of access. In my screen shot, that .zip was created with Windows Zip, the .7z is 7zip. Both have the attributes. And neither has to do with the file / archive format. It is dependent on the file system. NTFS, HFS+, Ext3 and Ext4 (Probably Ext2) also support journaling.

Comment: No lol; I meant the files _archived_ by Windows and 7-Zip, not the archives themselves. [This is what I meant.](http://www.filewin.com/cdn/images/img-filewin-7-Zip.jpg)

Comment: I think FileWin.com changed the contents of the screenshot I linked, because it seems like I'm asking what you answered instead of what I actually asked. Disregard the screenshot.

Comment: @AustinTFrench I added screenshots to my original question for clarification.

Answer (score 1):

[RAR](http://www.rarlab.com/technote.htm#timerecord) supports storage of modification, creation, and last access times. There's no (legal) free version of the compressor, though.

Comment: Oh... that archive format. While we're on terrible proprietary formats, how about .ace?

Comment: Alright, I updated my original question with screenshots. I believe I tested ACE years ago to do the same thing. If you could add screenshots of archiving in RAR here too that would be convenient for future viewers of this question (would catch more eyeballs). Otherwise, thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

Then I suppose you're stuck with "ZIP" and "CAB" on Windows without external applications that aren't native.  There's always "ARC" if that's still around.

Comment: Windows has a native `.cab` archiving utility?

Comment: Ah, good point.  I didn't research it before responding.

Comment: You were close! The .wim file format is capable of preserving all of these date timestamps IN ADDITION to many other NTFS attributes.

Answer (score 0):

what about 7z switch:

> -stl : set archive timestamp from the most recently modified file

Comment: I tried to run it with the -stl parameter and it failed (I put the screenshots in your answer). Could you please screenshot a case where this is successful?

Answer (score 0):

The `.wim` format stores not only Date Created and Date Accessed, but also stores symbolic links, hard links, alternate data streams, and file security:

[image: wim format]

[image: wim contents]

**However,** wim only stores files, it does not compress them.

Apparently .RAR and .ACE store Date Modified and Date Created, but I have not confirmed this for myself.

Bonus points to whoever wants to go through the other archive & compression file formats:

- .7z - Must specify "tc ta" in GUI parameters or -mtc -mta -mtm in Command Line parameters
- .s7z
- .ace - Asserted
- .afa
- .alz
- .apk
- .arc
- .arj
- .b1
- .b6z
- .ba
- .bh
- .cab
- .car
- .cfs
- .cpt
- .dar
- .dd
- .dgc
- .dmg
- .ear
- .gca
- .genozip
- .ha
- .hki
- .ice
- .jar
- .kgb
- .lzh
- .lzx
- .pak
- .partimg
- .paq6
- .pea
- .phar
- .pim
- .pit
- .qda
- .rar - Asserted
- .rk
- .sda
- .sea
- .sen
- .sfx
- .shk
- .sit
- .sitx
- .sqx
- .tar.gz - For compressing Unix files, no
- .tbz2
- .uc
- .uca
- .uha
- .war
- .wim - YES, but 7-Zip cannot compress with it
- .xar
- .xp3
- .yz1
- .zip - ONLY when archiving with 7-Zip, not Windows
- .zoo
- .zpaq
- .zz